# How to calculate standard deviation for the difference between two means?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, standardized-mean-difference

I am writing a paper where I am comparing the change over time of an intervention and control group. I have the mean and standard deviation for both groups at baseline and the mean and standard deviation following an 5 week period. I can then calculate the mean difference over time for each of the groups, but I'm not sure how I find the new mean value for this change. I also don't have access to the raw data, only have the means.

Information I have:
Control group:
Baseline mean, SD: 3.0, 0.9
5-week mean, SD: 2.0, 0.8
Mean difference: -1.0
SD of mean difference: ?
Intervention group:
Baseline mean, SD: 3.4, 0.7
5-week mean, SD: 2.0, 0.8
Mean difference: -1.4
SD of mean difference?

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the standard error of the difference because the baseline and 5-weak means are not independent: these are means of measurements taken from the same patients.